# Fancybox opens the gallery box but the first image doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery

I am a bit confused with the use of fancybox and the website is not really helping me with the confusion.

Quote from the website:

> Note - Galleries are created from elements who have the same "rel"
>   tag, example:

So I have this hidden div, where all images have the 'gallery' rel attribute:

```
<div id="gallery" class="none">
  <img src="img/fondo1.jpg" alt="" rel="gallery" />
  <img src="img/fondo2.jpg" alt="" rel="gallery" />
  <img src="img/fondo3.jpg" alt="" rel="gallery" />
  <img src="img/fondo4.jpg" alt="" rel="gallery" />
</div>
```

The link:

```
<a id="galleryBtn" class="galeria" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
```

and my trigger:

```
$('a#galleryBtn').fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    /*'transitionOut'   :   'elastic',*/
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    /*'overlayShow' :   false*/
});
```

The link opens the fancybox but it contains all images with a scrollbar instead of single images with the gallery next and prev buttons.

So what am i doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/wkP79/5/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
<div>
    <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://toniweb.us/gm/img/fondo1.jpg">Gallery</a>
    <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://toniweb.us/gm/img/fondo2.jpg"></a>
    <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://toniweb.us/gm/img/fondo3.jpg"></a>
    <a class="gallery" rel="gallery1" href="http://toniweb.us/gm/img/fondo4.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.gallery').fancybox({
       'transitionIn': 'elastic',
       'speedIn': 600, 
       'speedOut': 200, 
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CzMMB/

Comment: The problem is that i need an external link: mimiced my markup here http://jsfiddle.net/CzMMB/10/ it almost works, but only one image is loaded (with arrows, but next and prev is allways same) any ideA?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I don't understand why you cannot use the syntax that I provided. The Fiddle you provided is quite far away from the demo code on facebox.net, som I am suprised is doesn't break completely. :)

Comment: well thanks for your time anyway i will try myself... but i only add a different <a> to trigger it

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to post your answer here, when you find the solution. :)

Comment: Sure i will, but is very weird... are you familiarized with the plugin? please http://toniweb.us/gm  and click on Media gallery: first image won't work but the rest will... any thought about that? thanks!!